# Batch file to extract string from multiple text files

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have over a hundred text files formatted like this

```
    <TITLE> This is the title
    <SUBJECT> This is the subject
    <XTITLE>
```

I want to extract the title values using a Windows batch file, e.g. "This is the title" from each of these text files to a single output file, and include also the filename of the text file where these were found. Each text file can have multiple title tags. Example output below:

> This is the title textfile1.txt This is the second title textfile1.txt
>
> This is the third title textfile2.txt
>
> This is the fourth title  textfile3.txt

Anyone?

Comment: I'm talking about a Windows command line. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b/a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-3delims=<=>" %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\%%i") DO (
  IF "%%b"=="TITLE" ECHO(%%i %%c
  IF "%%a"=="TITLE" ECHO(%%i %%b
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The `if...%%a`  line will be invoked if there are no leading spaces, the `if...%%b` if there are leading spaces.

I changed the order of the report fields as that seemed to make more sense to me. If you truly want the report in the opposite order, simply revers the `%%i` and `%%a/%%b` in the `echo` statements.

This routine produces one line per input file.

---

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s/b/a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-3delims=<=>" %%a IN ("%%i") DO (
  IF "%%b"=="TITLE" ECHO(%%i %%c
  IF "%%a"=="TITLE" ECHO(%%i %%b
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Same routine adjusted to include scan of subdirectories. Note that in this case, `dir /s /b` includes the path in the listing.

You may wish to put the `echo`ed `%%i` in quotes in case of separators in path/filenames.

Comment: this is great magoo! how to change it from filename only to fullpath with filename?

Comment: change `%%i` in the `echo` statements to `%sourcedir%\%%i`

Comment: how to change if some files are in subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\folder_with_files"
for %%# in (textfile*.txt) do (

  for /f "tokens=1* delims=>" %%a in ('find "<SUBJECT>" "%%#"') do (
    if "%%b" neq "" (
        echo %%b : file %%#
    )
  )
)>>"c:\output.txt"
```

You might need to change the mask of the files in the first for loop and you need to change the PUSHD location

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I create an output file. Not really into programming

Comment: @john set `>>somefile.txt` at the end of the brackets  - like in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This method should run faster, specially if the files are large:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Group titles of same files in same array elements
for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=:>" %%a in ('findstr /L "<TITLE>" *.txt') do (
   set "t[%%a]=!t[%%a]!  %%b"
)

rem Show the titles
(for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set t[') do echo %%~Fa: %%b) > output.txt
```

For example, with these input files:

**textfile1.txt**

```
    <TITLE> This is the title
    <SUBJECT> This is the subject
    <XTITLE>

    <TITLE> This is the second title
    <SUBJECT> This is the subject
    <XTITLE>
```

**textfile2.txt**

```
    <TITLE> This is the third title
    <SUBJECT> This is the subject
    <XTITLE>
```

**textfile3.txt**

```
    <TITLE> Fourth title
    <SUBJECT> This is the subject
    <XTITLE>

    <TITLE> Fifth title
    <SUBJECT> This is the subject
    <XTITLE>

    <TITLE> Sixth title
    <SUBJECT> This is the subject
    <XTITLE>
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Folder\textfile1.txt:    This is the title   This is the second title
C:\Folder\textfile2.txt:    This is the third title
C:\Folder\textfile3.txt:    Fourth title   Fifth title   Sixth title
```